# Lead a life / live a life

Tags: grammar, etymology

"He can continue to lead a normal life" vs "He can continue to live a normal life.

What is the etymology of lead? Lead as in leader?

When can it be used? Can you" lead happily forever after"?

Comment: It's [definition 5 here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lead) ***Have or experience** (a particular way of life)*. Apart from the overwhelmingly more common ***life*** and the occasional ***existence***, I can't think of many other things you can "lead" in this sense. And although it's valid in this exact context to replace ***lead*** by ***live***, I don't think you can do it anywhere else.

Comment: "lead" and "live" are only synonymous in the one definition of lead.  Alternately, other words can be substituted for "live" that have different shades of meaning: "he suffered through life", "he enjoyed a normal life", "he experienced a normal life", for example.

Answer (score 3):

> He can continue to lead a normal life

Here, *lead* means *[to have or experience](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lead)*.

It is not a general synonym for *live*.

> When can it be used? Can you "lead happily forever after"?

When *lead* is used to mean *to have or experience*, it can only be used in reference to a life. It is not used in any other context. So you can’t say *lead happily forever after*.

However, you could say: *he led a happy life*.

Answer (score 1):

My take on it is that "He/she lead a good life" would mean that the person conducted himself (herself) in an honorable way during his/her lifetime.

Whereas, to say "He/she lived a good life" would mean that the person enjoyed their life in which they were happy (happy, healthy, successful, etc.).

So "lead a good life" implies some moral judgement, whereas "live/lived a good life" implies only personal happiness/success.

Comment: 'Lead a good life' _does_ demand a moral judgement. 'She lived a good life' may as you say be a comment on happiness (and/or longevity), but the moral reading is also possible here too.

Answer (score 0):

Figuratively, life is a path. A path may lead us to a place; we do not *lead* the path - we *follow* it. Similarly we may follow a life of simplicity, for example. Perhaps this seemed too passive for an obituary of a great leader and so was changed to "lead" and the phrase stuck. I'm only guessing.